# Passing data to main activity is lost

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

That issue took me few days of head-banging with no avail. In short I have two `Activities` for sake of the example I'll call them `MainActivity` and `SearchActivity`. The `MainActivity` has a button that takes you to a search screen which is the `SearchActivity` and there I have a button with preset value that I want to pass back to the `MainActivity`. So far so good. I click the button in debugger I can see my extra values and next breakpoint is in the onCreate in `MainActivity` when I get the extras there is nothing, none, all gone. SO here is the important part, the code:

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent search = new Intent(v.this, SearchActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(search, SEARCH_VIDEO_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == SEARCH_VIDEO_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String url = data.getExtras().getString("VIDEO_URL");
                if (url != null) {
                    txtUrl.setText(url);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SearchActivity.class**

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String videoUrl = "http://video-url.com";
                Intent data = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                data.putExtra("VIDEO_URL", videoUrl);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.project.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED"/>
        <data android:scheme="file"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.project.SearchActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

Comment: This code seems to work on my end. What is v.this from this line "Intent search = new Intent(v.this, SearchActivity.class);" ?

Comment: "V" is the MainActivity view "public void onClick(View v)" that I pass to the button event. I tried with `MainActivity.this` same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the class returning the result.

As Mikel points out in another answer:

[Intent(Context packageContext, Class cls)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29) *Added in API level 1*

> Create an intent for a specific component. **All other fields (action,
>   data, type, class) are null**, though they can be modified later with
>   explicit calls. This provides a convenient way to create an intent
>   that is intended to execute a hard-coded class name, rather than
>   relying on the system to find an appropriate class for you; see
>   setComponent(ComponentName) for more information on the repercussions
>   of this.

You aren't explicitly setting the data parameter as the documentation above states but instead attempting to add an Extra to a null Data object which fails.

Instead, I would change your class to the following:

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String videoUrl = "http://video-url.com";
                Intent data = new Intent();
                data.putExtra("VIDEO_URL", videoUrl);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This will initialize your Intent and allow you to add Extra data to it (this is also the normal way you would send back data, there isn't a need normally to send back a result which is tied to a specific Intent.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `key` "YOUTUBE_URL" to save the `extra` and the `key` "VIDEO_URL" to retrieve it, which doesn't exist. Change

```
String url = data.getExtras().getString("VIDEO_URL");
```

to

```
String url = data.getExtras().getString("YOUTUBE_URL");
```

Also, you are creating a new instance of `MainActivity` with the way you are creating the `Intent`. Change it to

```
Intent data = new Intent();  // empty constructor
            data.putExtra("YOUTUBE_URL", videoUrl);
```

You shouldn't go to `onCreate()` after calling `setResult()`. You should go to `onActivityResult()`

Comment: So the name of the parameter VIDEO_URL is the same on both sides misstepped it here. That's not the p e'er oven. The problem is extras is null once I receive the request

Comment: Is `onActivityResult()` being called? Did you try changing the `Intent` in the second `Activity` the way I suggested?

Comment: Yes, no good. There is definitely some problem with my main activity but I can't see what it is. I can pass extras to the SearchActivity but not back to the main one. In the debug panel extras is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Uh, did I miss something here? In SearchActivity, you identified the extended data with the key "YOUTUBE_URL", but in MainActivity, you try to retrieve it with the key VIDEO_URL. The two keys have to be the same.

I define keys for map-like structures such as shared preferences, intents, and so forth in a separate class, for example

> public class Utils {

In that class, I use the following to define a key:

```
public static final String KEY_VIDEO_URL = "com.example.myapp.KEY_VIDEO_URL";
```

In my main code, I refer to the key like this:

```
Intent incomingIntent = getResult();
String incomingURL = incomingIntent.getStringExtra(Utils.KEY_VIDEO_URL);
...
```

which helps me avoid some mistakes.

Comment: So the name of the parameter VIDEO_URL is the same on both sides misstepped it here. That's not the p e'er oven. The problem is extras is null once I receive the request.

Answer (score 1):

i copied your code and tried replicating your project on my box, i added a few lines so that i can run it like layout stuff... find below the code used..

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.stackoverflow;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final MainActivity mainActivity = this;
final int SEARCH_VIDEO_REQUEST = 1;
TextView returntext;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    returntext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.returnt);
    Button btnSearch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent search = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(search, SEARCH_VIDEO_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("ret", "returned data is: "+ data);
    // super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("ret", "returned data is: "+ data);
    if (requestCode == SEARCH_VIDEO_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String url = data.getExtras().getString("VIDEO_URL");
            if (url != null) {
                returntext.setText(url);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

SearchActivity.java

```
package com.example.stackoverflow;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    Button  btnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.searchret);
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String videoUrl = "http://video-url.com";
            Intent data = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            data.putExtra("VIDEO_URL", videoUrl);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

ManifestFile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.stackoverflow"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SearchActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

activity_main.xml (layout for main activity)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Main Activity Screen" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/returnt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textColor="#454545"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="received text.." />
```

search.xml (layout for search activity)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewkj1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Search Screen" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/searchret"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:text="Search Screen Button" />
```

I have exported the project as an archive so that you can easily import and test locally.. This works fine, so you can compare with what you have on your workspace.
Download [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75739641/StackOverflow.rar)

Hope this helps, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is related with this :

[Intent(Context packageContext, Class cls)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29)
    Added in API level 1

> Create an intent for a specific component. **All other fields (action,
>   data, type, class) are null**, though they can be modified later with
>   explicit calls. This provides a convenient way to create an intent
>   that is intended to execute a hard-coded class name, rather than
>   relying on the system to find an appropriate class for you; see
>   setComponent(ComponentName) for more information on the repercussions
>   of this.

Answer (score 0):

U can Try this:

```
    Bundle extras;
    String url;
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

            btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent search = new Intent(v.this, SearchActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(search, SEARCH_VIDEO_REQUEST);
                }
            });
        }

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == SEARCH_VIDEO_REQUEST) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


                      if (extras != null) {
                                  url = extras.getStringExtra("VIDEO_URL");

                                         }

                    if (url != null) {
                        txtUrl.setText(url);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run the code and got result with few corrections

modify

```
Intent search = new Intent(v.this, SearchActivity.class);
```

at MainActivity to

```
Intent search = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SearchActivity.class);
```

and modify

```
Intent data = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
```

at SearchActivity to

```
 Intent data =new Intent();
```

below is complete code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int SEARCH_VIDEO_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View btnSearch = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent search = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        SearchActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(search, SEARCH_VIDEO_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == SEARCH_VIDEO_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String url = data.getExtras().getString("VIDEO_URL");
                if (url != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "url"+url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //txtUrl.setText(url);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button btnSend = new Button(this);
        setContentView(btnSend);

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String videoUrl = "http://video-url.com";
                Intent data = new Intent();
                data.putExtra("VIDEO_URL", videoUrl);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `SearchAcivity`, instead of

```
Intent data = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
```

use an empty constructor, as in:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
```